# knitr will no longer compile: "Error in .First()"

Tags: r, knitr

When I opened R today (via RStudio), I saw the following come up in red text in the Console:

```
Loading required namespace: ffbase
Error in .First() : could not find function "load.ffdf"
```

This is also showing up in base R. I tried compiling an `.rnw` file via knitr today (using RStudio) and saw the following:

```
Loading required namespace: ffbase
Error in .First() : could not find function "load.ffdf"
Execution halted
```

I've never seen this issue before, the `.rnw` compilation has worked in the past, and no searching has helped me get around this issue.

I have no experience with `.Rprofile` files. When I typed in `.First`, I get the following:

```
> .First
function () 
{
    if (!requireNamespace("ffbase")) {
        stop("Please install package ffbase, otherwise the files cannot be loaded.")
    }
    env <- load.ffdf(".", parent.frame())
}
```

I'm not sure where this is coming from, what it is by default, etc..

Comment: Do you have a .Rprofile file ?

Comment: @etienne In the same folder as the `.rnw` file? No. I did, however, find an `.Rprofile` file in a different folder for some other files I ran previously and deleted it, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @etienne There is also no `.Rprofile` file in my working directory. I also tried opening base R (instead of RStudio) and it is happening there as well.

Comment: `.First` is usually a .Rprofile function. It could also be defined (I think) in Rprofile.site. Do you have the `ffbase` package installed ?

Comment: @etienne Yes, it is installed.

Comment: and does the code `load.ffdf(".", parent.frame())` runs if you launch it in the console ?

Comment: @Etienne No. 

`> load.ffdf(".", parent.frame())
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file '.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: An Rprofile file could be almost anywhere in your computer : installation directory or subdirectory for example. I think you should find the file where .First is defined

Comment: @etienne How would I go about doing that?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know. Look in your installation directory for starter and in any folder where you have R code. There is probably a fastest way but I don't know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing the following.

Start by doing `?.First`.

It states in the documentation:

> R searches for a user profile, a file of R code. The path of this file
>   can be specified by the `R_PROFILE_USER` environment variable (and
>   tilde expansion will be performed). If this is unset, a file called
>   `‘.Rprofile’` is searched for in the current directory or in the
>   user's home directory (in that order). The user profile file is
>   sourced into the workspace.
>
> ...
>
> Next, if a function `.First` is found on the search path, it is
>   executed as `.First()`.
>
> ...
>
> For the definition of the ‘home’ directory on Windows see the ‘`rw-FAQ`’ Q2.14. It can be found from a running `R` by `Sys.getenv("R_USER")`.

I did not have a `.Rprofile` file in the current directory, so I used `Sys.getenv("R_USER")` which led me to the home directory, which had a `.Rprofile` file which I deleted, and now the error is gone.