# R Markdown Saved on Dropbox won't compile

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to compile the basic example R markdown beamer presentation (I also tried compiling the pdf and the html, neither of which worked).

It works flawlessly when I save the markdown file on my local mac book air. But when I save the file on my dropbox, I get the following error:

```
Loading required namespace: ffbase
Error in .First() : could not find function "load.ffdf"
Execution halted
```

The example file does not call ffbase in any way. I think the problem has something to do with accessing my rprofile, but I can't figure out why that would be an issue.

How do I get the markdown file to knit the pdf/html/beamer when the script is saved on dropbox?

Comment: Have you come across [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000115/knitr-will-no-longer-compile-error-in-first)?

Comment: @lao_zhang - that was very helpful!